# onclick event on background image in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a div in html inside that created one textbox and assigned a background image to it, and i want to make an onclick event to that input field's background image.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss").onclick = function() {
    alert("Hello"); 
};
```

```css
.textboxcss {
    background-image: url("../images/sub.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-position: 8px 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input class="textboxcss" id="default" type="text">
</div>
```

I see get the image correctly... But i cant get onclick this way. Is there any other way?

Comment: Can't you use `focus` event instead?

Comment: Do you tried on fiddle.. Post link here if you have.

Comment: @ Sandeep Nayak:i am also tried that one but it is not

Comment: Why don't you try target the ID rather than the Class. Here is a working fiddle targeting the ID above: https://jsfiddle.net/2q8yfLuq/

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. So you should attach the onclick of each element in the array.

Comment: @lekshminair: Did the answer solve your issue. If not please share your full code. And also check the updated answer of mine, as I refined it little bit.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated the answer

Try `querySelector()` instead,

```
(function(){
    document.querySelector(".textboxcss").onclick = function () {
       alert("Hello!"); 
    };
}());
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7n7eko/3/

---

**And if you want to use `getElementsByClassName()`**, you have iterate through selector elements and bind the onClick event. Because getElementsByClassName() returns an `Array`.

```
(function(){

    var textInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(textInputs, function () {
        this.onclick = function () { 
            alert("Hello!");
        };
    });

}());
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sj7n7eko/5/

---

#### Also noticed that you are using jquery in your updated question,

Then you can simply use jQuery for it

```
$(".textboxcss").click(function(){
   alert("Hello!");
});
```

**Or** if you are adding element dynamically,

```
$("body").on("click", ".textboxcss", function(){
   alert("Hello!");
});
```

Comment: :get this error message  Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: In the fiddle ? which browser you are using? Because I tested on both firefox & chrome

Comment: you tried as it is in the https://jsfiddle.net/sj7n7eko/1/ right ? I mean HTML/JS both ?

Comment: make sure when you use querySelector(".textboxcss"). you need to add `.` or `#` depending on you selector type whether it's a class or an ID

Comment: Is you text input element injects dynamically? if not try, `(function(){
  document.querySelector(".textboxcss").onclick = function() { alert("Hello!"); };
}());`

Answer (score 0):

Should be work...

```
function Alerta(table) 
{
   alert("Hello"); 
}

<div><input class="textboxcss" id="default" type="text" onclick="Alerta()">
</div>
```

**Note**: You can change the event which is launching your JS function. Onblur, Onfocus,... Check this list out [List Events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array. So you should at least select the first element in the array.

```
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss")

 // Assign click event
 elements[0].onclick= function () { 
    alert("Hello"); 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I can sense some design issue here, but being specific to your question, you can achieve it by `onfocus` or `onclick` of input element.

```
(function() {
    // your page initialization code here
    // the DOM will be available here
    document.querySelector(".textboxcss").onfocus = function() {
        alert("Hello");
    };
})();
```

Alternatively,

```
(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss")[0].onfocus = function() {
        alert("Hello");
    };
})();
```

OR bind onclick event if required,

```
(function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss")[0].onclick = function() {
        alert("Hello");
    };
})();
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ardcx40q/1/)

Comment: :i get this error messageCannot set property 'onfocus' of null

Comment: @lekshminair Checkout the demo, It's working there. You can also try alternative method as return in my answer.

Comment: "Cannot set property onfocus", This error means it's not able to get document.getElementsByClassName("textboxcss")[0] selector in your page. Kindly ensure you are running javascript only when document is ready.

Comment: @lekshminair Update my answer so that it runs only when document is ready. Try now !

Answer (score 0):

Create another class with the backgroud image you wanted to assign on click. And on click add that another class( with **!important** written in css for backgroud image )

Comment: @user3713916 sorry can you please give me a example

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign your .css class to background separately. Sharing full code for better understanding.

```
.imageControl {
background-image: url("../images/sub.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-position: 8px 13px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="imageControl"></span>
    <input id="default" type="text">
</div>
```

Click Event:

```
document.getElementByClassName("imageControl").addEventListener("click", function() {
// To-Do on click of background image
});
```